# How can I draw a triangular Membership function of Fuzzy logic

Tags: tikz-pgf

I’ve been trying to recreate the following image in latex.

[image]

The MWE I've got so far

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{A Title}
\date{\today}
\author{Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (b) at (2,2);
        \coordinate (c) at (4,0);
        \coordinate (d) at (-1,0);
        \coordinate (e) at (5,0);
        \coordinate (f) at (-1,3);
        \coordinate (g) at (2,0);
        \coordinate (h) at (-1,2);
    
        \draw (a)--(b)--(c)--(a);
        \draw (d) -- (e);
        \draw (d)--(f);
        \draw [densely dotted] (b)--(g);
        \draw [densely dotted] (b)--(h);
        \draw(a) node[anchor=east,align=center] {a};
        \draw(b) node[anchor=south,align=center] {b} ;
        \draw(c) node[anchor=west,align=center] {c};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Some Caption}
    \label{fig:tikz picture}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I complete the picture. The main problem I guess is the x-y axis along with the labeling. I was also wondering how can we add `\columnwidth` or `\textwidth` options to it, so it can be adjusted in a single column in ieee format.

Comment: You've got way too much coordinates defined here. You just need a, b and c. All the rest can be drawn with Ti*k*Z commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**
Added are before forgotten labels `1` and `c`

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{A Title}
\date{\today}
\author{Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Straight Barb,
                        every label/.append style={text height=2ex}]
\draw[->]   (0,0)  coordinate[label=below left:0] (o) 
                    -- ++ (5,0) node[below left] {$U$};
\draw[->]   (o)     -- ++ (0,4) node[below left] {$\mu_A(U)$};
    \coordinate[label=below:$b$] (b) at  (1,0);
    \coordinate[label=above:$A$] (A) at  (2,3);
    \coordinate[label=below:$c$] (c) at  (2,0);

    \coordinate[label=below:$a$] (a) at  (3,0);
\draw[thick]    (a)--(A)--(b);
\draw[densely dashed] 
            (o |- A) node[left] {1} -| (c);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Some Caption}
\label{fig:tikz picture}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Jasper Habicht, thank you very much for correcting erro0r in my MWE.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you needed a regular triangle (with adjustable length), here's the solution I worked on (while Zarko beat me to it):

[image: triangular membership]

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{A Title}
\date{\today}
\author{Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \def\l{1.5}
            \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (b) at (3-\l,0);
        \coordinate (A) at (3,{\l*sqrt(3)});
        \coordinate (a) at (3+\l,0);
        
        \draw[<->] (0,{\l*sqrt(3)+.5}) node[above] {$p_A(U)$}|- (6,0) node[right] {$U$} node[midway, below left] {$0$};
    
        \draw (b) node[below] {\strut $b$} --(A) node[above]{$A$} --(a)node[below] {\strut $a$};
        
        \draw[densely dashed] (o|-A) node[left]{$1.0$} -| (o-|A) node[below]{\strut $c$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A triangular membership function}
    \label{fig:tikz picture}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: to get a good fit on a document, one would go with either 1.5 or 2. Although, having adjustable lengths is a good tweek

Answer (score 0):

I usually do the examples for triangular fuzzy numbers as follows:
[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
  
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
%title = teste,
%axis lines=middle,
axis x line=middle,
axis y line=middle,
xmin = -1,
xmax = 6,
xtick=data,
xticklabels={,,,$m$,,$n$,,$p$},
ymin = 0,
ymax = 1.1,
extra x ticks={0},
%xtick = {-1,0,1},
%xticklabels = {$-1$,$0$,$1$},
ytick = {1},
%yticklabels = {$1$},
xlabel = {$x$},
ylabel = {$\varphi_F (x)$},
every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=west},
every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=south},
]
\draw [red,line width=1pt,line join=round] (axis cs:-1,0) -- (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs: 3,1) -- (axis cs:5,0) -- (axis cs: 6,0);
\draw (axis cs: 3,1) node[above] {$\varphi_F$};
\draw [dashed, help lines] (axis cs:3,0) -- (axis cs:3,1) -- (axis cs:0,1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```